# link to local .m2 repository in pom.xml

Tags: maven

Can I get a link to the .m2 directory in my pom.xml file. At the moment I am directing it at **${user.home}/.m2/repository** but some of the users may have their .m2 folder elsewhere. I have tried ${localRepository} but it just creates that directory in my current directory instead of jumping to it plus it creates a weird structure like id: **local url :file/.m2/repository/***. I want to link the .m2 repository directory

Comment: Your settings.xml is responsilbe for this. Apart from that the default should work...so without explicit configuration...Are there any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for:

```
 ${settings.localRepository}
```

as described in the [List of predefined Maven properties](https://github.com/cko/predefined_maven_properties/blob/master/README.md).